# onload for content being loaded by Ajax

Tags: jquery, onload

I'm using jQuery-load to load content into a div container. Unfortunately the callback fires already when the content is completely inserted. At this time it is not ensured that the images are completely loaded. However I need to do some modifications to the images that require that they are completely loaded. Unfortunately a div container doesn't support an onload listener. Registering a listener to each image tag would get too complicated (I could find a PHP based solution instead). Is there a simple solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this problem further I found that using the load event for the image is not that complicated as I considered it to be. The reason is that my actions refer to the image itself. I found the following solution:

```
    function setcss(im) {
        wdth = im.width();
        if (calcSupport) var imcss = { maxWidth: wdth + "px", width: "calc(100% - 105px)", height: "auto" };
        else var imcss = { width: "70%", height: "auto" }
        im.css(imcss);
    }
    $(sel + " img[src*='.jpg']").each(function () {
        var im = $(this)
        im.on("load", function () {
            setcss(im);
        });
        // Check if image is already loaded (browser might have had it in cashe)
        if (im.get(0).complete) { setcss(im); console.log("already loaded"); }
    });
```